# Two column multiplication with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multiplication

I've the following code. It worked but since I updated my server to the last php version and since mysql_fetch_array is deprecated the code isn't working for me and I am having difficulty finding a solution. Any help is welcome.

I've two columns that have a quantity and a price. I want to sum all pieces x price to find the total amount of products that I've in stock.

```
$all_products_sumquery_raw = mysql_query(
    "SELECT SUM(products_quantity * products_price_sorter) AS grand_total
    FROM products WHERE products_quantity > 0"
);

$test1 = mysql_fetch_array($all_products_sumquery_raw);

echo '<h2>Total: <span class="totalUred">' . 
    number_format($test1[0], 2, ',', ' ') . 
    '</span>$.</h2>';
```

Comment: What version of PHP MySQL are you using?

Comment: First, **all** mysql_* functions are deprecated. Second, that last line is not valid PHP. Check your error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysqli to get it working again:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT SUM(products_quantity * products_price_sorter) AS grand_total FROM products WHERE products_quantity > '0'";
$all_products_sumquery_raw = mysqli_query($link, $query);

/* associative and numeric array */
$test1 = mysqli_fetch_array($all_products_sumquery_raw, MYSQLI_BOTH);

echo '<h2>Total: <span class="totalUred">' . 
    number_format($test1[0], 2, ',', ' ') . 
    '</span>$.</h2>';
```

[How to use mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)